# How can I retrieve a variable from a function?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables

I know there are a few items out on the internet over how to achieve this, but I can't get it to work...
Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

I currently have two functions. I want to use the variable (`$new_data`) from function1 inside function2.

Function 1:

```
function manipulate_form_submission( $record, $ajax_handler ) {
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );
    $form_data = $record->get( 'fields' );
    
    //change the names of fields before we send them somewhere
    $new_data = array(
        'email'         => isset( $form_data['email']['value'] ) ? $form_data['email']['value'] : '',
        'url'           => isset( $form_data['url']['value'] ) ? $form_data['url']['value'] : ''
    )
}
```

Function 2:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'so_payment_complete' );
function so_payment_complete( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $response = wp_remote_post( 'https://mywebsite.com/insert_values.php', array( 'body' => $new_data) );
    
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you can use `update_option` and `get_option` over here. There are many possible ways to do so. Now it depends on your logical implementation too

Comment: Is there any common value between two functions? If Yes, then you can use that as a dynamic option key in both the functions

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize the variable outside the two functions like this:

```
<?php
$new_data = false;
function manipulate_form_submission( $record, $ajax_handler ) {
    global $new_data;
    $new_data = "New value";
}
function so_payment_complete( $order_id ){
    // The variable is accessible here
    global $new_data;
    echo $new_data;
}
?>
```